# How to install X11 legacy apps (desktop apps) on the M10 aquaris

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch

I just got my brandnew M10 ubuntu edition and i love it. I need webdav accesss on it but couldn't get it working, so i thought if I install Nautilus on the tablet i could get it working as easily as on the PC.

I couldn't find a complete guide on how to install X11 legacy apps on the tablet and can't figure it out myself, so if somebody could link a easy to use guide for the M10 i would be glad.

I already installed the terminal from the appstore to use apt-get but this terminal seems to be restricted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using apt-get can break your system (no more OTA updates at least, and potentially more breakage) and it wouldn't help you anyway because legacy apps need Libertine/Puritine to run. You would need to enable r/w access to your system partition for apt-get to work at all, but that seems to be strongly discouraged.

There is currently no supported way to install legacy X11 software, but it should all be ok in a few weeks when OTA11 comes out and we get the Libertine GUI app and other tools to make it work.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This german article [link](https://ikhaya.ubuntuusers.de/2016/02/04/canonical-bestaetigt-veroeffentlichung-von-bq-aquaris-m10-fhd/) claims that one could install x11 apps on the M10 in a "container" with a terminal and apt-get, are those containers the same like libertine or is this a complete different way?

Comment: Yes, from what I have gathered that would be a libertine container. It's true that there are a few command line tools installed (and the preinstalled LibreOffice, Gimp and Firefox are packaged that way), but I didn't get it to work so far and decided to wait for OTA11 (the next update) where it will be fully supported, including a GUI app.

Comment: Here's an interesting discussion including instructions: https://plus.google.com/101402903185277489519/posts/h1frtNV4Har

It seems that sometimes you can just locally install an application in your home directory (so you don't have to mount the system partition r/w), but in other cases you need to properly install things inside a container. I haven't tested it myself yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get netbeans working in the container, it was ok, but Ive been exploring and using apt-get and now I realized I shouldn’t have done that. So I am erasing doing a hard reset here, and will wait for the OTA11

Answer (score 1):

https://drive.google.com/?usp=docs_web gives an example of how to install Inkscape in a libertine/puritine container. It worked fine for me and I installed a couple of other X11 packages (PSPP and wavesurfer) the same way. So with a bit of trial and error, it's possible. GNU Octave didn't install successfully though. OTA11 will make life easier, though, I hope.

Comment: Your link only leads me to my googledrive home folder, maybe you can fix this?

Comment: Sure, it's moved to [link](http://notyetthere.org/installing-more-puritine-apps-on-the-m10/ )

Comment: I urge caution though. It worked for some X11 software, but the one I really wanted to GNU Octave, just bricked my M10 tablet on several attempts, forcing me to re-flash it. So now I just await a fully tested Libertine installer.